# Find and take the last picture from a file or gallery. Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android

I want to take the last picture from a file and put it on an ImageView.

Here I create the file:

```
public File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}`
```

Comment: I want to import the last picture from My Files/ Pictures and i want to put in on an ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works:-

```
//getting all files within the storage dir (unsorted)
File[] listFiles = storageDir.listFiles();

//a Comparator is used to order Arrays (or other Collections)
Comparator c = new new Comparator<File>(){ //File-specific Coparator

    public int compare(File file1, File file2){
        //this Comperator uses timestamps for orders
        long tsFile1 = file1.lastModified(); 
        long tsFile2 = file2.lastModified();

        //timestamps are Longs, so we can re-use the Long Comparator
        return Long.valueOf(tsFile1).compareTo(tsFile2);
    } 
};

//apply the comparator on the array:
Arrays.sort(listFiles, c);  //now it's sorted by day

//from the sorted array, the last one is the desired file!
String imgPath = listFiles[listFiles.length-1].getAbsolutePath();

//as above
Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
```

Comment: and i create the file after picture... and on the other activity i try to import that

Comment: Yeah, so the lastModified file will always be that picture, supply a comparator to the Arrays.sort() method that sorts files by File.lastModified()

Comment: Implemented the comparator as well